# Writing python code to convert linux read, write and execute octal format to the string

Tags: python

The permissions of a file in a Linux system are split into three sets of three permissions: read, write, and execute for the owner, group, and others. Each of the three values can be expressed as an octal number summing each permission, with 4 corresponding to read, 2 to write, and 1 to execute. Or it can be written with a string using the letters r, w, and x or - when the permission is not granted. For example: 640 is read/write for the owner, read for the group, and no permissions for the others; converted to a string, it would be: "rw-r-----" 755 is read/write/execute for the owner, and read/execute for group and others; converted to a string, it would be: "rwxr-xr-x" Fill in the blanks to make the code convert a permission in octal format into a string format.

```
def octal_to_string(octal):
  result = ""
  value_letters = [(4,"r"),(2,"w"),(1,"x")]
  # Iterate over each of the digits in octal
  for ___ in [int(n) for n in str(octal)]:
      # Check for each of the permissions values
      for value, letter in value_letters:
          if ___ >= value:
              result += ___
              ___ -= value
          else:
              ___
  return result

print(octal_to_string(755)) # Should be rwxr-xr-x
print(octal_to_string(644)) # Should be rw-r--r--
print(octal_to_string(750)) # Should be rwxr-x---
print(octal_to_string(600)) # Should be rw-------
```

Please help me to fix this problem

Comment: This question is missing any mention of what should happen if the owner has no permissions for their own file. Something like `066` is not a valid Python numeric literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- An easier way.

  ```
  def octal_to_string(octal):
      permission = ["---", "--x", "-w-", "-wx", "r--", "r-x", "rw-", "rwx"]
      result = ""
      # Iterate over each of the digits in octal
      for ___ in [int(n) for n in str(octal)]:
          result += permission[___]
      return result

  print(octal_to_string(755)) 
  print(octal_to_string(644)) 
  print(octal_to_string(750)) 
  print(octal_to_string(600))
  ```

[image: Output1]

- According to your logic.

  ```
  def octal_to_string(octal):
     result = ""
     value_letters = [(4,"r"),(2,"w"),(1,"x")]
     # Iterate over each of the digits in octal
     for ___ in [int(n) for n in str(octal)]:
        # Check for each of the permissions values
        for value, letter in value_letters:
            if ___ >= value:
                 result += letter
                 ___ -= value
            else:
                 result += "-"
     return result

  print(octal_to_string(755))
  print(octal_to_string(644))
  print(octal_to_string(750))
  print(octal_to_string(600))
  ```

[image: Output2]

Answer (score 2):

```
def octal_to_string(octal):
 result = ""
 value_letters = [(4,"r"),(2,"w"),(1,"x")]
 # Iterate over each of the digits in octal
 for i in [int(n) for n in str(octal)]:
    # Check for each of the permissions values
    for value, letter in value_letters:
        if i >= value:
            result += letter
            i -= value
        else:
            result += '-'
 return result
```

Comment: Consider explaining your answer and how it solves OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
def octal_to_string(octal):
    result = ""
    value_letters = [(4,"r"),(2,"w"),(1,"x")]
    # Iterate over each of the digits in octal
    for x in [int(n) for n in str(octal)]:
        # Check for each of the permissions values
        for value, letter in value_letters:
            if x >= value:
                result += letter
                x -= value
            else:
                result += "-"
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def octal_to_string(octal):
    result = ""
    value_letters = [(4,"r"),(2,"w"),(1,"x")]
    # Iterate over each of the digits in octal
    for i in [int(n) for n in str(octal)]:
        # Check for each of the permissions values
        for value, letter in value_letters:
            if i >= value:
                result += letter
                i -= value
            else:
                result += "-"
    return result
    
print(octal_to_string(755)) # Should be rwxr-xr-x
print(octal_to_string(644)) # Should be rw-r--r--
print(octal_to_string(750)) # Should be rwxr-x---
print(octal_to_string(600)) # Should be rw-------
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def octal_to_string(octal):
    result = ""
    value_letters = [(4,"r"),(2,"w"),(1,"x")]
    # Iterate over each of the digits in octal
    for y in [int(n) for n in str(octal)]:
        # Check for each of the permissions values
        for value, letter in value_letters:
            if y >= value:
                result += letter
                y-= value
            else:
                result+="-"
    return result
```

print(octal_to_string(755))

## rwxr-xr-x

Answer (score 0):

```
def octal_to_string(octal):
    result = ""
    value_letters = [(4,"r"),(2,"w"),(1,"x")]
    # Iterate over each of the digits in octal
    for x in [int(n) for n in str(octal)]:
        # Check for each of the permissions values
        for value, letter in value_letters:
            if x >= value:
                result += letter
                x -= value
            else:
                result +="-"
    return result
    
print(octal_to_string(755)) # Should be rwxr-xr-x
print(octal_to_string(644)) # Should be rw-r--r--
print(octal_to_string(750)) # Should be rwxr-x---
print(octal_to_string(600)) # Should be rw-------
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you question was particular about  *"Fill in the blanks to ....a string format."* 
So here we go;

```
def octal_to_string(octal):
    result = ""
    value_letters = [(4,"r"),(2,"w"),(1,"x")]
    
    for num in [int(n) for n in str(octal)]:
        
        for value, letter in value_letters:
            if num >= value:       #checks if num not exceeds value of value_letters
                result += letter   #adds coherent letter to result 
                num -= value       #substracts for new value to check next permission
            else:
                result += "-"
    return result
    
print(octal_to_string(755)) # Should be rwxr-xr-x
print(octal_to_string(644)) # Should be rw-r--r--
print(octal_to_string(750)) # Should be rwxr-x---
print(octal_to_string(600)) # Should be rw-------
```

In this script here, 
`for num in [int(n) for n in str(octal)]:` 
Does 4 things; `n` iterates for each string octal numbers, `int(n)` converts those str values as integers, list comprehension converts obtained integers as list and finally `num` iterates for every integer in the list comprehension.

And, since given `value_letters` are tuples thus `for value, letter in value_letters:` iterates for for value and letter individually. 
I hope I was able to help you. :D

Answer (score 0):

answer is

```
def octal_to_string(octal):
 result = ""
 value_letters = [(4,"r"),(2,"w"),(1,"x")]
 # Iterate over each of the digits in octal
 for i in [int(n) for n in str(octal)]:
    # Check for each of the permissions values
    for value, letter in value_letters:
        if i >= value:
            result += letter
            i -= value
        else:
            result += '-'
 return result
```

explanation:

consider octal = 755

```
  # Iterate over each of the digits in octal
  for i in [int(n) for n in str(octal)]:
```

here it will create a list like this

> [7,5,5]

here in the comment, I show how the loop works for the 7

```
value_letters = [(4,"r"),(2,"w"),(1,"x")]
for value, letter in value_letters:     # 1st loop | 2nd .. | ...
 if i >= value:                         # i=7 , 7>4  | i=3 , 3>2   | i=1 , 1=1 
            result += letter            # result = r | result = rw | result = rwx
            i -= value                  # 7-4=3      | 3-2=1       | 1-1=0
        else:
            result += '-'                                         # | i = 0 , 0<1
 return result                                                    # | result = rwx-
```

then it will do the same process for each number in the created list

I hope the answer is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `stat.filemode`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html#stat.filemode